# Rails 4.2.5.1 and foundation-rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

So im trying to install `gem foundation-rails` and it keeps giving me an error:

**console error:**

[image]

**Browser error**

[image]

**Solution worked:**

removing `//= require foundation` from appliaton.js fixed the problem but i dont think this is the right solution. any suggestions that worked for you guys? thank you.

**Application.css**

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require foundation_and_overrides
```

**Application.js**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Untitled" %></title>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
```

Comment: can you share your application.js and application.css

Comment: @Saad added app.js and app.css

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to include the gem 'execjs' and gem 'therubyracer' in your gem file . Add gem 'execjs' and gem 'therubyracer' to the gemfile and bundle install.

Comment: I tried your solution, but the problem persist. thanks for the input